# Reduce image size without changing resolution android studio

Tags: android, image

In my android app, I use the Camera intent to click a photo and upload the same to my server for processing. However, there is a requirement that the resolution of the image should be more than 500X500.

The default camera resolution is much higher these days and hence the desired resolution is not an issue. However, in most cases the resolution is much higher and the image size comes up to 3 MB or so. Because of this, it takes longer to upload the image to server, especially in areas where internet connectivity is poor.

I would like to reduce the size of the image, preferably down to 100 KB or so, without reducing the resolution.

My code for capturing the image through intent is:

```
     imageHolder = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cPhoto78);
     imageHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File outputFile1 = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/APDCLSBM/APDCL1.jpg");
            outputFile1.delete();// Deletes the existing photo
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error in clicking picture",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
           Intent a = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(photoCamera.this,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                        photoFile);
                a.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                startActivityForResult(a, 1);
            }

        }
    });
```

The following function creates the image file and path:

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String imageFileName = "APDCL1";
    File storageDir = new File(
            getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
    File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName+".jpg");

    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.d("path1",currentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}
```

Please suggest a way

Comment: Do you mean 'reduce file size'?

Comment: `The following function creates the image file and path:`. No. Luckily it does not. It creates a File object only. And you know a path. But there is no image-file- yet. That is left to the camera app.

Comment: Once the picture is taken load the file in a bitmap (if that is possible). Then compress to jpg file again using a lower quality percentage.

Comment: `"Error in clicking picture"`  You can do better. Add `ex.getMessage()` to the string.

Comment: `finish();`. That is too harsh. Replace by `return;`.

Comment: `File outputFile1 = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/APDCLSBM/APDCL1.jpg");
            outputFile1.delete();// Deletes the existing photo`. Better remove those useless lines.

Comment: @blackapps, these are snippets from my code and hence some of the lines may seem useless to you, but has great use to me :)

Comment: And, do you have a solution to my issue? If yes, please provide the same. I am quite clear in my post that I want to reduce the image size without reducing the resolution.

Comment: I was quite clear in telling you how you can do that i think.

Comment: When I compress to jpg, does the resolution remain the same?

Comment: @blackapps were you trying to say something like my answer

Comment: @Tanmoy where do you want to upload the file, firebase ?

Comment: @Abhinav Chauhan, that was indeed what i had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
String imageFileName = "APDCL1";
File storageDir = new File(
        getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName+".jpg");
try{
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath);
}catch(Exception e){ e.printStacktrace(); return null;}

   File reducedSizeImage = new File.createTempFile("name",".jpg",location);
 try ( FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(reducedSizeImage)) 
 
      {

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,20, outputStream); // this line will reduce the size , try changing the second argument to adjust to correct size , it ranges 0-100

 
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     }

   return reducedSizeImage // otherwise upload this file
}
```

**Have a good day**

Comment: Your code works. Ok. (Well you should return null if there is an exception. You continue twice as if nothing had happened ). But is too complicated. Do away with the ByteArrayOutputStream. You can directly compress to outputStream.

Comment: @blackapps is it ok now?, i just tried to least touch his code and just add to it

Comment: I still see that ByteArrayOutputStream. So no.

Comment: @blackapps now?

Comment: Yes, now is the time.

Comment: To sit down and rest under a palm tree like i do ;-)

Comment: @Tanmoy welcome, and if you are uploading to firebase you don't have write that code too